# NullPointerException when getting image width and height

Tags: java, tomcat

I have an upload webapp and I have to calculate image width and height when save the image. When I run the project under tomcat in eclipse, everything just work. But when I run it in tomcat outside eclipse, I get a NullpointerException.

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("temp", "jpg");
//decode image stream and write to temp file. 
BufferedImage bImage = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(tempFile ));
int width = bImage.getWidth();
int height = bImage.getHeight();
```

The different as I can see is when I run in eclipse, the tempfile is created under windows user temp folder whereas when running in tomcat, the tempfile is created under tomcat temp folder. I have write the file size to log, and both time, they actually have size.

I add more code here so that everyone have experience can have me

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/octet-stream")
@ResponseBody
public String handleStreamUpload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
 InputStream imageEncodeStream = request.getInputStream();
 File tempFile = File.createTempFile("-TEMP-", ".temp");
 MessageDecoder decoder = new MessageDecoder(
            imageEncodeStream, tempFile);
 decoder.decode();

 String resolution = getResolution();
 //generate unique image name and add resolution to image name.
}
```

Code of the decoder:

```
public void decode() throws IOException {

//Some secret decode part here.

InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    int bs = 16384;
    byte[] buf = new byte[bs];

    try {
        int off = 0;
        for (;;) {
            int bytes = in.read(buf, off, bs - off);
            if (bytes < 0) { // EOF
                if (off > 0) {
                    fos.write(buf, 0, off);
                }
                break;
            }
            if (bytes == 0) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2);
                } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
                    ignore.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if ((off += bytes) == bs) {
                fos.write(buf);
                off = 0;
            }
        }
    } finally {
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

Update : I solved the problem by config the maven-compilter-plugin to 1.6. Then build the war file and deploy to Tomcat again. It works just fine. Don't really know the root caused yet ??? Can anyone explain it to me ?

Comment: Does the file exist?  Do you have write permissions to the `temp` directory?

Comment: I don't get it, you call `createTempFile` but then try and read the file as an image. Surely you need to write something to the file??

Comment: The file actual exist but in tomcat temp folder I cannot open it, windows say it's corrupted. But when run in eclipse it work just fine.

Comment: Are you properly closing the stream you're using to write the file?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of flaws in the code. I am sure you must have overlooked it.

This particular code will not work. The

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("temp", "jpg");
```

creates an empty file with the name tempXXXjpg. So when you read it using

```
BufferedImage bImage = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(tempFile ));
```

It will store a null value in the bImage.

And it is likely to give you a null pointer exception. You need to read an already existing file and not create a temp file. If the requirement is to create a temp file , then copy a file and create a temp file out of it.

**EDIT**
I sense two problems here, mentioned below:
1)The location of the original image relative to the tomcat webapp directory, might not be accessible to the application code which tries to read the file.

2) If the code is not very secret, I would like to see your code which is reading the file and I would also like to see what is the image path that code is using.

Could you please paste that as well?

Comment: I have removed the decode image stream part in the code posted. I created the temp file, decode the inputstream and write to the temp file. I have determined that the decode part return differently between two env. But still don't know what caused that?

Comment: I don't read the file. I just got the encoded input stream, decode it and write it to the temp file. However, in eclipse the decode run fine and I can open the file. When run tomcat standalone, there's some problem with the decode and the file is corrupted. Still debugging.